# Map array of mongodb to objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, mongodb, mapping

I am trying to map the array on the basis of index. I am able to map all of the array at once only how do I map each array with index?

```
html:
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever user click on Start it should display only the value of one object:

```
<div class="col" *ngFor="let val of data" style="background-color: whitesmoke;">
  <div class="col-sm-11">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Id: {{val._id}}</h5>
        <h5 class="card-title">Title: {{val.title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Description: {{val.description}}</p>
        <button  [routerLink]="['question']">Start</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
  data: Model[] = []; 
    getData() {
        this.http.get<any>('https://node-quiz1.herokuapp.com/quizzes/').subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
          // @ts-ignore
          this.data = response;
        });
```

Model.ts

```
export interface Model {
  title:string;
  description:string;

  Question1:string;
  Q1Option:boolean;

  Question2:string;
  Q2option1:string;
  Q2option2:string;
  Q2option3:string;
  Q2option4:string;
}
```

Mongodb : I have data on the following ways in Mongodb;
what I am trying is when user click on first the it should display only data that is related to first index

```
_id : 6088a6c72f78db0015e93666
title : "easy"
description : "Atempt all"
Question1 : "First question goes here"
Q1Option : true
Question2 : "second question goes here"
Q2option1 : "option "
Q2option2 : "option "
Q2option3 : "option"
Q2option4 :"option "

_id : 6088b00f2f78db0015e93667
title : "Medium"
description : "Atempt all"
Question1 : "First question goes here"
Q1Option : true
Question2 : "second question goes here"
Q2option1 : "option "
Q2option2 : "option "
Q2option3 : "option"
Q2option4 :"option "
```

Comment: Why when you are trying to get the data with Angular using type any instead of using your Model class  !

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Oh sorry I have `data: Model[] = [];`

Comment: What i'm talking about is in your http call :   data: Model[] = []; 
    getData() {
        this.http.get<Model[] >('https://node-quiz1.herokuapp.com/quizzes/').subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.data = response;
        });

Comment: @RebaiAhmed I have not specified if data is string or boolen in backend so I used `any` while doing get request.

Comment: with Typescript, you can define many types for your field,   Q1Option:boolean | string :) I hope it helps

Comment: @RebaiAhmed my question is how can I get only one index data. Example if i click first index start the i want to get data related to first index only.

Comment: Please check my answer about finding by index , if it helps please upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find method:

```
selectedElement= categories.data(quizz => quizz._id == _your_idex);
```

Comment: `your_index` where do i need to assign ?

Comment: In your click or OnChange function, you will get the selected element with an index!